# XGboost feature mismatch error in predict statement

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost

I was trying to train a XGboost model by splitting my training into Train and Test. In the test set I removed the result column and passed it to the predict() function. This is what my code looks like

```
    #splitting training set to test and train set

    x_train ,x_test = train_test_split(TrainingData,test_size=0.3) 
    result_x_test = x_test.Response
    x_test = x_test.drop('Response', 1)

    #XGboost algorithm to build a model/ predictor
    #Converting data to Matrix format

    XTrain = x_train.as_matrix()
    YTrain = x_train["Response"].as_matrix()
    XTest = x_test.as_matrix()

    #Training the model

     TrainingModel = xgb.XGBClassifier(max_depth=3, n_estimators=300, learning_rate=0.05).fit(XTrain, YTrain)
     Prediction = TrainingModel.predict(XTest)
```

The error I get is the following

```
 ValueError: feature_names mismatch: 

['f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9', 'f10', 'f11', 'f12', 'f13', 'f14', 'f15', 'f16', 'f17', 'f18', 'f19', 'f20', 'f21', 'f22', 'f23', 'f24', 'f25', 'f26', 'f27', 'f28', 'f29', 'f30', 'f31', 'f32', 'f33', 'f34', 'f35', 'f36', 'f37', 'f38', 'f39', 'f40', 'f41', 'f42', 'f43', 'f44', 'f45', 'f46', 'f47', 'f48', 'f49', 'f50', 'f51', 'f52', 'f53', 'f54', 'f55', 'f56', 'f57', 'f58', 'f59', 'f60', 'f61', 'f62', 'f63', 'f64', 'f65', 'f66', 'f67', 'f68', 'f69', 'f70', 'f71', 'f72', 'f73', 'f74', 'f75', 'f76', 'f77', 'f78', 'f79', 'f80', 'f81', 'f82', 'f83', 'f84', 'f85', 'f86', 'f87', 'f88', 'f89', 'f90', 'f91', 'f92', 'f93', 'f94', 'f95', 'f96', 'f97', 'f98', 'f99', 'f100', 'f101', 'f102', 'f103', 'f104', 'f105'] ['f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9', 'f10', 'f11', 'f12', 'f13', 'f14', 'f15', 'f16', 'f17', 'f18', 'f19', 'f20', 'f21', 'f22', 'f23', 'f24', 'f25', 'f26', 'f27', 'f28', 'f29', 'f30', 'f31', 'f32', 'f33', 'f34', 'f35', 'f36', 'f37', 'f38', 'f39', 'f40', 'f41', 'f42', 'f43', 'f44', 'f45', 'f46', 'f47', 'f48', 'f49', 'f50', 'f51', 'f52', 'f53', 'f54', 'f55', 'f56', 'f57', 'f58', 'f59', 'f60', 'f61', 'f62', 'f63', 'f64', 'f65', 'f66', 'f67', 'f68', 'f69', 'f70', 'f71', 'f72', 'f73', 'f74', 'f75', 'f76', 'f77', 'f78', 'f79', 'f80', 'f81', 'f82', 'f83', 'f84', 'f85', 'f86', 'f87', 'f88', 'f89', 'f90', 'f91', 'f92', 'f93', 'f94', 'f95', 'f96', 'f97', 'f98', 'f99', 'f100', 'f101', 'f102', 'f103', 'f104']
    expected f105 in input data
```

The 105th column is the result column and I think it is throwing error because of missing result column. But the test set must not contain the result set right?
What is the fix for this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you still keep the target variable in `XTrain`, which you do not want, i imagine. And the target (`'Response`) feature is missing in `XTest`.

So the quick solution would be to do 
`XTrain = x_train.drop("Response", axis=1).as_matrix()`

I personally would also suggest not to do `.as_matrix()`: the sklear API handles well `pd.DataFrame` and that would keep meaningful feature names, and would ease debugging of this issue, for example